# how to automate ssh-keygen -t rsa in linux?

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm new linux OS, I try to copying some file from more than one remote system. Many times i have give login inforamtion in terminal, how can i this process automate and access file from each remote system...

I try:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html

I refer above links but i can't accesss more remote system without password.. how can i do this process, and I trying to perl also Net::SSH but i can't understand that, can you any one help to this...?

```
Solution as : perl is better, shell script..
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a process which should need to be automated. Generate one SSH key on your workstation and copy the public key to `.ssh/authorized_keys` on all the remote systems you are connecting to - this doesn't require that you run `ssh-keygen` more than once.

Comment: oh k k, can you please explain with example two more remote connect.. and how to store this file...

Comment: The web page which you linked to in your question already contains instructions on how to do precisely this!

Comment: can you have any link for multiple ssh-key generate..? please

Comment: Because when i gererate another keys "ssh: connect to host 192.156.0.34 port 22: Connection refused" so please with explain with example...

Comment: The machine you're trying to connect to isn't running a SSH server (or is behind a firewall that blocks it). This is not a problem that `ssh-keygen` can solve.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused by your question. The link you provided - http://www.linuxproblem.org/art_9.html  - shows you exactly how you need to do what you want to do.

You do not have to regenerate a different key for each host you want to connect to - simply reuse the same key - i.e. you should only have to run ssh-keygen once. Follow the rest of the steps as many times as you have hosts to connect to.